# Motional e.m.f. & transformer e.m.f

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Two_phenomena), there are two ways to generate induced e.m.f.:

1. Keep the circuit stationary while moving the magnet, giving rise to ***transformer e.m.f.***
2. Keep the magnet stationary while moving the circuit, giving rise to ***motional e.m.f.***

For either of the methods, the equation governing the induced e.m.f. produced is just Faraday's law of induction $$\varepsilon = -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$

The idea of magnetic flux $\Phi_B$ involves a non-zero area since $$\Phi_B = \int\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$$ Will we be able to generate *transformer e.m.f.* if we are using a straight wire (i.e. moving the magnet while keeping the wire stationary)? If yes, which is the non-zero area that concerns $\Phi_B$? Similarly, which is the non-zero area that concerns $\Phi_B$ when generating motional e.m.f. with a moving, straight wire?

Comment: using faradays law, no. as needs a closed loop to be valid. However using the differential form, and solving for the E field for a given distribution can be used to find the Emf about a open path

Comment: For the magnetic field, Similarly you could use int  vxb.dl